# Gmail randomly spoils html emails

Tags: html, css, email, layout, gmail

I've spent all my ideas why it happens and how to avoid it.
I compose HTML email and sometimes gmail breaks a layout.
It may insert random symbols (basically space character) and that leads to unpredictable visual artefacts like on a screenshot:
An area outlined with red contains html entity ▼ with artificially space character inserted by Gmail. Other arrow-down symbols stay unchanged.

[image]

Comment: Also very weird that there's a space. Can you use `&#9660;` to begin with? I don't know how that behaves in email.

Comment: I'm generating `&#9660;` string to produce arrow symbol. If I open this html in web browser as single page, than it's ok, nothing is broken ever.

Comment: Ah ok. I think I misread the rest of the question.